# Checking length of a float

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to check the length, in digits, of a float variable, but I don't know the correct syntax to use.  I've looked this up and I couldn't find an answer.

My code is a simple if statement:

```
if (currentNumber.digits < 3) {  //If the number has less that three digits, I don't know what to put here to get it working

    //code
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by length?  Do you mean just the digits before the decimal point?  Just the ones after?  Or all of them?

Comment: Sorry, just the ones before the decimal.

Comment: You can round (ceil) the decimal log to get your number of digits.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you trying to do some formatting like adding thousand separators? (aka 1,000,000?) If so you should use [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: No, I want the user input to be limited by digits, not value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>

//...

int digits = (int) ceil(log10(number));
```

The extra logic for negative numbers is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: No. See comment at top or my answer. You have to round up, not down, to get the number of digits.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(int) ceil(log10f(float))`?

Answer (score 2):

As there doesn't seem to be a correct answer :

```
int digits = (int) ceil(log10(currentNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a  NSString with your value and check the length of that:

```
NSString *stringNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", currentValue];
int length = stringNumber.length
```

You can probably subtract 1 from the length to consider the decimal point.

[Here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) the reference for the `NSString` doc so you can check what the methods do, in case you don't understand them.

EDIT: If you want the numbers before the decimal point you can do this after what I posted:

```
[stringNumber substringToIndex:[stringNumber rangeOfString:@"."].location].length
```

And then use this value in the conditional of your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
int digits = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", variable] length]
```